# How to add one to each digit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the assignment:

Write a function that is passed in a string and returns a new string with the same characters as the original, except all digits are replaced with a digit that is 1 higher. 9s are replaced with 0s.

- increase_digit('1ab2') → '2ab3'
- increase_digit('56789') → '67890'
- increase_digit('abcde') → 'abcde'

This is what I have so far:

```
number = ""
s = str(number)
l = []

def increase_digit(text):
    for num in s:
    num = int(num)
    num += 1
if num > 9:
    num = 0
    l.append(num)
else:
    l.append(num)
```

Comment: You already lose me here: `number = "" ;  s = str(number)`. What does that conversion do if you're starting out with a string, as the example and your dataset above indicates? Do you need it?

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach is wrongly indented but also doesn't check for digits and increment at all.

Instead, you could iterate over the string and increment the digits by one. If you just take the last digit from the increment then you convert `'10'` to `'0'` as required:

```
def increase_digit(text):
    return ''.join(str(int(c)+1)[-1] if c.isdigit() else c for c in text)
```

Examples:

```
increase_digit('1ab2')
# '2ab3'
increase_digit('56789') 
# '67890'
increase_digit('abcde')
# 'abcde'
```

Comment: Thank you for that!  I was making this way too complicated.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Downvote is not a harmful thing but rather beneficial, The one who downvoted must be downvoting for a reason, if they would tell the reason, I'd be happy to delete/rectify my answer.

Comment: @Chris_Rands `text.translate(str.maketrans(string.digits, string.digits[1:]+string.digits[0]))` is even more beautiful. However, OP is novice and requesting help with **his** code (as he stated, some assignment). I believe these answers belong on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. Plus, its kinda useless to just say "I'll give new code". We usually request askers to provide code and this is a good question, so I'd expect answers to modify OP's code rather than write new one.

Comment: @MYGz yes, but more often than not they don't in my experience. I can take it. And I'm sure Chris can. But I also see it happen a lot towards newbies which is quite pathetic IMO - picking on some one one's own size and all that. But I'm digressing.

Comment: @dale No problem, happy to help, checkout Uriel's answer too if you want a solution that is closer to your original code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
a = ['1ab2', '56789', 'abcde']
a2 = [''.join([chr(ord(c)+1) if c.isdigit() else c for c in b ]).replace(':','0') for b in a]
print a2
```

Output:

```
['2ab3', '67890', 'abcde']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if num is a digit before casting it to an int.

Here is my code and the output

```
def increase_digit(text):    
    l = []
    for num in text:        
        if num.isdigit():
            num = int(num)
            num += 1
            if num > 9:
                num = 0
        l.append(str(num))
    return l

print(increase_digit('1ab2'))
print(increase_digit('56789'))
print(increase_digit('abcde'))
```

The output of my code is this:

```
['2', 'a', 'b', '3']
['6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You forgot a few things:

1. Check if `num` is a digit (`num.isdigit()`).
2. Return `num` to string form.
3. Return the array joined.

Here are the required changes for this issues:

```
def increase_digit(text):
    l = []

    for num in text:
        if num.isdigit(): # issue 1
            num = int(num) + 1
            if num > 9:
                num = 0
            num = str(num) # issue 2
        l.append(num)
    return ''.join(l) # issue 3
```

### More advanced:

`9 + 1 = 10`. Thats the only case above `9`, and can be solved without condition by taking the number last digit - `0`, So

```
if num > 9:
    num = 0
num = str(num)
```

go into `str(num)[-1]`. We can move on to eliminate the multiline condition -

```
num = int(num) + 1
num = str(num)[-1]
```

as `num = str(int(num) + 1)[-1]`, and now we have a small loop -

```
for num in text:
    if num.isdigit():
        num = str(int(num) + 1)[-1]
    l.append(num)
```

that can turn into a list comprehension (for the `for`) and an ternary `if-else` condition -

```
l = [str(int(num) + 1)[-1] if num.isdigit() else num for num in text]
```

and, combined with the final return we get

```
def increase_digit (text):
    return ''.join(str(int(x) + 1)[-1] if x.isdigit() else x for x in text)
```

You could keep with this substitution methods and use `string.digits`, `str.translate` and more to make the code more elegant - but I believe this level is far enough for an homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

happening because you're increasing 9, before the comparison "num > 9"?

Also is this the output or the required output?

```
"increase_digit('1ab2') → '2ab3'
 increase_digit('56789') → '67890'
 increase_digit('abcde') → 'abcde'"
```

Comment: I believe it's the required one and that num>9 is correct as he wants to catch all numbers that were originally 9 so adding one then checking to see if it is greater that 9 is a valid way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Such rotations are the canonical example for using the modulo operator `%`:

```
def increase_digit(text):
    return ''.join(str((int(c)+1) % 10) if c.isdigit() else c for c in text)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand your  code but you seem to be trying to do something like:

```
''.join([str((int(s)+1) % 10) if s.isdigit() else s for s in inp])
```

Oops, these do look similar ;-) Hi @Chris_Rands

Comment: @Chris_Rands I wasn't suggesting it. It didn't escape my notice that you were downvoted as well. I'll delete my comment since apparently it can be misread that way.